# mysql increment variable using case

Tags: mysql, case

I have two tables `marks` and `exams`.

In the `marks` table I have `studentid`, `mark1`, `mark2` and `examid`-foreign key from `exams` for different exams.

I want to get distinct student id and their number of failures in one single query.

The condition for failure is `mark1+mark2 <50 or mark1<30`. For e.g. If a student having studentid 1 has 15 entries(15 exams) in marks table and the same student failed in 6 so I want to get result as '1' and '6' in two columns and similarly for all students. For this case I wrote query using 'case' and is given below

```
select
    distinct t1.studentid,
    (@arrear:= 
        case
            when (t1.mark1+t1.mark2) <50 OR t1.mark1 < 30
            then @arrear+1 else @arrear
        end) as failures
from  marks t1, exams t2,
(select @arrear := 0) r
where t1.examid = t2.examid group by t1.studentid;
```

But the above query failed to give correct result. How can I modify the query to get correct result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You don't need to use variables to help you.

```
select 
    m.studentid,
    sum(case when m.mark1 + m.mark2 < 50 or m.mark1 < 30 then 1 else 0 end) as failures
from
    marks m inner join exams e
on
    m.examid = e.examid
group by
    m.studentid
```

The `case` statement works out if the result is a failure or not and returns 1 for fail, 0 for no fail. Summing the result of this (`group`ed by `studentid`) gives you the number of fails per studentid

Oh and the join makes a more efficient join between your two tables :)

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` here since you're grouping on `studentid`. You will already get just one row per student.

Comment: Thank you CResults for your response. Your Query gave the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need variable @arrear. You can get your info using only query

Try this:

```
select
    distinct t1.studentid,
    sum(
        case
            when (t1.mark1+t1.mark2) <50 OR t1.mark1 < 30
            then 1
            else 0
        end
    ) as failures
from  marks t1, exams t2
where t1.examid = t2.examid group by t1.studentid;
```

Comment: Thank you Joe Taras for your response. Your Query gave the correct result.